# How is nested print() used in python?

Tags: python

I am learning Python now, so having very petty doubts, sometimes stupid even. So if find something resembling to one of the either, please ignore!

The `print()` in python prints onto the standard output. So basically, if I write

`print('Hello World')`

I get to see `Hello World` on the in the output. But what happens when I have multiple `print()` nested within each other? Something like this..

`print(print("Hello World"))`

Output is:

```
    Hello World
    None
```

Similarly, if I have:

`print(print(print()))`

Then the output is:

```
   //blank line
   None
   None
```

I am unable to understand what is happening here, please if anyone could explain, that would be a great help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `print()` function returns `None` (like most functions that are called for their side effects). The outer `print()` is just printing that return value.

There's no particularly good use case for ever nesting `print` functions like that.

Comment: @Wobble Ok, but the `print()` returns a string in the first case "Hello World", then how come it even prints `None` after that?

Comment: It doesn't return a string. It prints a string to the standard output.

Comment: It prints `None` because the inner `print()` returns `None`